# Use a ref to a DOM element both in parent and children components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Following this example https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html I'm passing the `ref` callback from the parent to the child as prop.

```
function SearchInput(inputRef) {
  function onCLick(){
  //Dosomething and...
  //Focus on input element using ref
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input ref={inputRef} onCLick={onCLick} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Parent(props) {
 function focusSearchElement() {
   if (searchElement)
     searchElement.focus();
 }

  return (
    <div>
      My input: <SearchInput inputRef={element => searchElement = element} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

While the focus set in the parent by `focusSearchElement` works correctly, I'm not able to set the focus to the input from `SearchInput` component.

What I want to accomplish is set the focus in the `onCLick` function, but I'm not sure if it's possible and if so, how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a small example:

```
function SearchInput({inputRef: refCallback}) {
    let inputRef;
    function onClick(){
      inputRef.focus();
    }

    function inputRefHandler(ref){
      inputRef = ref;
      refCallback(ref);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input ref={inputRefHandler}/>
        </div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>input focus</button>
      </div>
    );
}

function Parent(props) {
    let searchElement;
     function focusSearchElement() {
       if (searchElement)
         searchElement.focus();
     }

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={focusSearchElement}>parent focus</button>
        <div>
          my input: <SearchInput inputRef={element => searchElement = element} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}
```